# jQuery range slider / price refine mobile touch

Tags: jquery, mobile, user-interface, range, slide

I'm looking for a jQuery UI slider for refining price which works on mobiles.

I've tried these: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/03/4-jquery-price-range-slider-example.html

I've also tried these: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/4-jquery-mobile-price-sliders-range-select/

They all work very well on my computer, but work very poorly on my mobile.

Any suggestions?

Code example:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
  value: 2,
  min: 1,
  max: 3,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    cameramen = ui.value;
    return calcTotal();
  }
});
```

Comment: Use this link if you are working for mobile http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/

Comment: Thanks, some useful info. :)